No loader is configured for ".vue" files: app/javascript/HelloWorld.vue
In my API-only rails app, I am using Vue 3 with jsbunding using jsbundling-rails gem for the frontend.
I have setup package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "esbuild": "^0.21.5",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "vue": "^3.4.29"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets",
    "build:js": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets --watch",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss build app/javascript/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.29",
    "esbuild-plugin-vue3": "^0.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38"
  }
}


And in my esbuild.config.js
// esbuild.config.js

const { build } = require('esbuild');
const vuePlugin = require("esbuild-plugin-vue3")

build({
  entryPoints: ['app/javascript/application.js'],
  bundle: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  format: 'esm',
  outfile: 'public/assets/main.js', // Output bundled JavaScript file in Rails' public directory
  plugins: [vuePlugin()],
  loader: {
    '.ts': 'ts',  // TypeScript loader
    '.tsx': 'tsx', // TypeScript with JSX
    '.vue': 'vue', // Vue Single File Components
  }
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));


My entrypoint file application.js
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue';

const app = createApp({
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  template: `
    <div id="app">
      <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue 3 + TypeScript + Rails API!" />
    </div>
  `
});

// Mount Vue app directly to a DOM element in your Rails views or layouts
const mountElement = document.getElementById('app');
alert(123)
if (mountElement) {
  app.mount(mountElement);
} else {
  console.error('Could not find element with id "app"');
}


The issue is, I still get above error even I have added esbuild-plugin-vue3 in my esbuild.config.js
As soon as I run npm run build:js
I get below error,
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".vue" files: app/javascript/HelloWorld.vue
Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.
I checked many issues like this on different platforms and everyone mentioned to add "esbuild-plugin-vue3" as a package and include it in plugins in esbuild.config but it doesn't resolve my issue
